# Mapping between graph and complement

Tags: algorithm, graph-theory

I have two **isomorphic** graphs.

Given a **self-complementary** graph `G`, is there any **faster algorithm** to find the **vertex mapping** between `G` and its **complement**?

I'm thinking there should be a faster way because we know that the 2 graphs are both **isomorphic** and **complementary**.

**EDIT**
Sorry I shoudld've been more clear:
I already know of the VF2 algorithm which has time complexity of O(V^2) in the best case and O(V!·V) in the worst case. Which makes it slow to compute mappings for the large graphs (1k vertices, 500k edges) that I'm working with.

I was just asking if given this special case of the graphs being both **isomorphic** and **complementary** there exists a faster solution.

Comment: Faster than *what*? Also, could you present a small example?

Comment: Note that there is [cs.se] where your question may be more appropriate.

Comment: @zabuza - faster than GI between non-complementary graphs. One way to say this is "can we exploit the complementary property of the pair of graphs to speed up isomorphism"

Comment: Is this helpful : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/217061/graph-theory-complements-of-isomorphic-graphs-are-isomorphic or this https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2560743/shift-a-graphs-isomorphic-complement-vertices-to-make-it-look-like-its-original

Comment: @gilleain: yes the second link seems to be a similar problem. I've edited the question to make it more clear.

Comment: Better now, thanks.

Comment: Ok, so one thing that occurs to me is that finding an isomorphism between G and c(G) is equivalent to finding an automorphism of G so I don't see that it sould necessarily be much faster

Comment: The other is that for such large graphs I would recommend using nAUTy or similar third-party library as other approaches will be hard

Comment: Given that the graph is complementary, does it have any other particular structure to it? For example, is it strongly regular?

Comment: No, it hasn't got any particular structure.

Comment: @BogdanB - What I don't understand is how you have the pair of graphs but you don't already have the mapping between them. If you start with G, and then calculate c(G), then the mapping comes with that. Or do you have the pair (G, c(G))?

Comment: I calculate c(G) by inverting the adjacency matrix. Is there a better way to do it? Giving the mapping?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is the isomorphism problem for self-complementary graphs.

It might be expected
that
the isomorphism
problem
would
in fact be easier
to tackle when
restricted
to self-complementary
graphs
or digraphs,
because
of their
strong
structural
properties.
**It turns
out,
however [Colbourn
and
Colbourn
1978,
1979],
that
the isomorphism
problem
for self-complimentary graphs
is polynomially
equivalent to the general
isomorphism
problem;**
we say that
it is
isomorphism
complete
. Even if we just want to know whether
a graph
or digraph
is self-complementary, the complexity is the same.
This
makes it improbable
that
there
will be any simple
and
quick test
for recognising
sc-graphs;
for
example,
comparing
the chromatic
polynomial
of a graph
with
that
of its
complement will not tell us whether
it is self-complementary
(see
1.59).
Recognition
and isomorphism
of self-complementary
graphs
therefore
take
on added
importance.
They
could
provide
a cure
for what
has been nicknamed
the isomorphism
disease,
and
even settle
the famous
(or notorious)
question
of whether
P is equal
to NP, as we shall
see.

p.97 of this article:
Self-complementary graphs and generalisations: a comprehensive reference manual.
Alastair Farrugia
University of Malta
August 1999

http://www.alastairfarrugia.net/sc-graph/sc-graph-survey.pdf